# jqTransform Select - how to implement Scroll to letter typed

Tags: jquery, jqtransform

I have a website using jqTransform.

Unfortunately, one of the major issues with this otherwise good bit of code, is that the select drop-down box no longer responds to the keyboard (ie. pressing S to go to the first option beginning with S).

There was apparently a work around on:
http://www.techapparatus.com/jqtransform-select-problem-with-keyboard-type-solution

However, this is no longer available - I tried contacting the author, but have received no response.

Has anyone else got any worked examples?

Comment: Facing same issue, Have you got any sulotion?